# Create Task Workflow for Annual Review

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

Is this possible? Can someone assist me with the correct way if it is. I would like to create a Workflow that will be run each year to create a task. One custom list has a choice field Yes/No. I have a custom Task List with a related lookup field back to my custom list. What I need is a process/workflow that a manager each year can run to read through the first list and for each record that has a YES automatically create a task and assign to 2 users.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done with a REST call in the workflow. 
Make a call to select the Id's of the list items where choice field is equal to 'Yes' and filter results by date range. Then loop through each result creating a new item in your task list and setting the lookup field to the Id returned. Also, set any other columns you need including the 'Assigned To' field when creating the new item.

NOTE: I created this as a list workflow and it was initialized through the 'Task3' item, but it would probably serve better as a site workflow.

[image]

Here is an example of the url. I used the 'Created' column to filter dates:
[image]

This is the list I used in the example:

[image]

This is the task list the items were created in:
[image]